# Looping through a form and populating from an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form and a javascript object.

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="title">
    <input type="text" name="image">
</form>

var myObject = {title: 'this is the title', image: 'image.jpg'}
```

Is there a way to run through the form inputs, and it any of the input names match the keys in the object, set the value?

Please note, I wish to run through the form and not the object, as the object has lots of other data in it which is not relevant to the form (not shown in example).

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
$("#myForm input:text[name]").each(function() {
    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    for (var key in myObject) {
        if (key == name) {
            $(this).val(myObject[key])
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With this you don't ever loop the object, but you'll have to write an if-clause for every attribute:

```
var myObject = {title: 'this is the title', image: 'image.jpg'}

$('#myForm input').each(function()
{
    if($(this).attr('name') === 'title')
    {
        $(this).val(myObject.title);   
    }
});
```